# Map a set of Images into a image tag in react component

Tags: reactjs

I have 20 images in my src folder `src/images` i want to map that images into the image tag in a `app.js`. How to do this? 
Below is my Setup, I Get error by this.

```
import ImageDetails from "../data/ImageDetails";

{
    ImageDetails.map((Images) => {
        return (<img alt="doubt" src={ImageDetails.images} />)
    })
}
```

My Json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
     "images": "../../assets/images/sample1.jpg",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
     "images": "../../assets/images/sample2.jpg",
  },
  .
  .
  So on upto 20 images...
]
```

Comment: Presumably that's because the URLs are relative paths from the servers perspective, is `ImageDetails` a file being included in the client? If so, the image paths need updated to be relative to the client.

Comment: All my images are inside a src folder, src/images/images.jpg i want it to map. i am learning react btw

Comment: Yes but the path doesn't mention anything about a `src/images` folder (presumably because that's a server-side directory). Although, as someone has commented, you should be using `Image.images` inside the map and not `ImageDetails.images` (this might be the issue)

Comment: can you provide a screenshot for `console.log(ImageDetails)` output?

Answer (score 1):

import ImageDetails from "../data/ImageDetails";

```
{
    ImageDetails.map((Images) => {
        return (<img alt="doubt" src={Images.images} />)
    })
}
```

You need to use Images instead of ImageDetails inside the .map

Comment: There could be three reasons your image is not loading - 
1. The specified path in img src tag is not correct.
2. There are speed issues at the user’s side and the image is too heavy to be loaded.
3. You web server got slower or taking much time to complete the request.
Is your path correct?

Comment: To understand more about the src path - https://www.jquery-az.com/html-img-src-image-source-attribute-with-path-possibilities-5-examples/